Opening activity when tapping a notification of a foreground service causes animation or flashing even when application is already opened
I was able to remove the animation of sliding from right to left, but a flash remains which looks bad.
This removes the animation:
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0) // No animation

How do i just hide the notification bar when tapping the notification and the activity is in the background?
